# Shell script to rename multiple files from their parent folders

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sh, rename

I'm looking for a script for below structure:

Before :

```
/Description/TestCVin/OpenCVin/NameCv/.....
/Description/blacVin/baka/NameCv_hubala/......
/Description/CVintere/oldCvimg/NameCv_add/.....
```

after:

```
/Description/TestaplCVin/OpenaplCVin/NameaplCv/.....
/Description/blaapcVlin/baka/NameaplCv_hubala/......
/Description/aplCVintere/oldaplCvimg/NameaplCv_add/.....
```

I want to rename " Cv or CV or cV " >> "aplCv or aplCV or aplcV" in all folder by regular expression...

My script does look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "Input your Directory path: -> "

read DIR

cd "$DIR"

FILECASE=$(find . -iname "*cv*")

LAST_DIR_NAME=""

for fdir in $FILECASE
do
        if [[ -d $fdir ]];
        then
            LAST_DIR_NAME=$fdir

        fi

        FILE=$(echo $fdir | sed -e "s/\([Cc][Vv]\)/arpl\1/g")
        echo "la file $FILE"
        if ([[ -f $fdir ]] && [[ "$fdir" =~ "$LAST_DIR_NAME" ]]);
        then
           FILECASE=$(find . -iname "*cv*")

            tmp=$(echo $LAST_DIR_NAME | sed -e "s/\([Cc][Vv]\)/arpl\1/g")
            fdir=$(echo $fdir | sed -e 's|'$LAST_DIR_NAME'|'$tmp'|g')
        fi

        mv -- "$fdir" "$FILE"
done
```

But it throws an error ..:(

How could I write it to rename the files according to their folder names?

Comment: .. by `regulator exception` ... What is that?

Comment: ... regulator expression  :D.. i write wrong spelling

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: can you help me ? devnull. I searched 4 day  but not result as i want.

Comment: error  :  mv: rename ./Description/Testaplaplaplin to : No such file or directory .............

Comment: Use 'set -x' option at the start. It will help to debug the script. Check this [link](http://tecadmin.net/debug-shell-script/#).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "Input your Directory path: -> "
read DIR
cd "$DIR"
MYARRAY=$(find . -iname "*cv*" )

touch "tmpfile"

for fdir in $MYARRAY
do
    echo "$fdir" >> "tmpfile"
done

MYARRAY=$(tac "tmpfile")

for fdir in $MYARRAY
do
    cd "$fdir"
    prev=$(cd -) 
    base=$(basename $fdir)
    cd ..
    nDIR=$(echo "$base" | sed -e "s/\([Cc][Vv]\)/arpl\1/g") 
    mv "$base" "$nDIR"
    cd $prev    
done

rm -f "tmpfile"
```

Also one issue i think `tac` command not included in  Mac OS X.Instead `tac` use `tail -r` like  `MYARRAY=$(tail -r "tmpfile")`

Comment: hello! @Jayesh. thank you very much. I had to rely on it. And see the code is probably correct as I think his logic. Tomorrow opens up his computer to type on . See how it truly thankful Jayesh :).

Comment: in script you post .  I runned it . but alert erro "line 15: tac: command not found " why ????

Comment: which system you are using?

Comment: If MAC osx them probably it's not supported so use `tail -r`.

Comment: system i using is Mac osx .....but replace MYARRAY=$(tail -r "tmpfile") to MYARRAY=$(tac "tmpfile") still error :( ..

Comment: :it not alert error "tac command not found " but error :./te.sh: line 19: cd: ./adt bundlemacx86_6420130917/ eclipse/configuration/ org.eclipse.osgi  /bundles/235/1/. cp/icons/full/ arplarplarplarplarplarplarplarplcview16: No such file or directory
mv: rename arplarplarpview16 to arplarplarp  larplarplarplarplarplarplcview16:  No such file or directory

Comment: do you add my skype ? my skype :  trandieuthanh .

Comment: @Teddy Added you. can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Always make a backup before playing with this kind of scripts.

You can try the following:

```
find . -iname '*cv*' -exec echo 'mv {} $(echo $(dirname {})/$(basename {}|sed s/cv/apl/gi))' \;|tac|xargs -i bash -c 'eval {}'
```

This uses -exec to print commands for renaming.
The second arguments are generated by using shell substitutions to replace cv with apl in the last part of the path.
tac is used to reverse the order of the commands, so that we do not rename a directory before working with its contents.
Finally, we eval the commands with bash.

Also, do not use -exec in a permanent script. Please read the security warnings about exec in the find man-page.

Comment: hello,Trygve Flathen .so thank you. Now i've read all your assistance. I'm watching and I've revised my request. Request "apl" is inserted into the front of the file or folder "cv, CV, CV Cv" .:( .I was wrong earlier .. while post, my english level is not good.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to use my method with your original regex in sed.

Comment: I simplified it a bit and changed the behaviour to your revised request:

`find . -iname '*cv*' -exec echo 'mv {} $(dirname {})/$(basename {}|sed '\''s/\(cv\)/apl\1/gi'\'')' \;|tac|sh`